# How to browse the internet using Epiphany web browser

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am using the Raspberry pi 3 for one of our projects. I am in the middle of bringing up the system.

I face difficulty browsing the internet using Epiphany. I have eth0 connected to Raspberry Pi and am able to see the IP assigned accordingly, but when I run Epiphany to access the internet I couldn't connect to any sites. It gave error message that reads as follow: "Oops! It was not possible to show this website". What have I missed?

Can anyone out there help me?

Comment: Are you in an isolated network (firewalled) ?

Comment: Can you ping google.com. 8.8.8.8. or the IP of your router/gateway?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the Internet used to be **very slow** with epiphany web browser, it turns out the problem was... The browser! I bought a wireless WiFi dongle, still slow... I fixed it by installing **iceweasel.**

Boom, lightning fast!
Hopefully the solution will work for you (for me if fixed slow internet, hopefully it fixes connection error)

Search up: iceweasel

I think to install it run:
sudo apt-get install iceweasel